# I have the depressed cubic equation $x^3+(2/3) x+74/27=0.$

Tags: roots, cubic-formula

When I solve it with Wolfram Alpha, I get one real root $-1.2414,$ and two complex roots: $0.6207+1.35i$ and $0.6207-1.35i.$ This makes sense.

When I use Cardano's formula in Wolfram Alpha, I get $0.85+1.21i.$ Why is this? Does Cardano's formula always work? I am bewildered.

Comment: There's a mathematica stackexchange site. Your question might be better asked there.

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Show us your work with Cardano. And learn MathJax.

Comment: Alpha will give you the exact forms of the roots.  That can help in finding your error as you can trace where the terms come from.

Comment: To answer part of your question, yes, Cardano's formula always works, when properly applied. However, Cardano's formula is tricky to get simple $a+bi$ answers from, which gives lots of opportunity for errors to slip in.